# How to play more than one audio file in android?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple project where I am making an app that allows me to play more than one audio file.

I want to play more than one file, can someone help me? I created two buttons in which one plays one song and the other button plays another. However, one button only works and plays the recent audio that i added in. Does anybody know what to do?
Here is an example of my code:

```
package com.example.soundboard;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = null;
    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer1 = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.herbimage);
        myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.icecream);
        myMediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.boxandstring);
        Button soundclip1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button soundclip2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        soundclip1.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                myMediaPlayer.start();
                myMediaPlayer.pause();

            }
        });

        //second sound clip
        soundclip2.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                myMediaPlayer1.start();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: I can see a myMediaPlayer.pause(); on the first button, is that on purpose?

Comment: Look at [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) API, I believe it suits your needs.

Comment: the pause was just for practicing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SoundPool Class
its for more than one sound